# Why the last column index is too low for the function Offset in Apache POI and how to deal with it?

Tags: java, apache-poi

I'm using Apache POI to do some manual calculations and recently I faced with the problem that I'm not able to use `OFFSET` formula for columns that start from 255 index.

For example

```
XSSFCell cell = sheet.getRow(1).createCell(1);
cell.setCellFormula("OFFSET(IV220,0,1)");

XSSFFormulaEvaluator evaluator = 
workbook.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();

evaluator.evaluateInCell(cell)
```

And the value inside the `cell` variable is always `#REF!`. Also, keep in mind that the column index for `IV220` is 255. In case if I'd decrease the column index by 1 then it would produce a valid value:

```
cell.setCellFormula("OFFSET(IU220,0,1)");
```

I found out that the `org.apache.poi.ss.formula.functions.Offset` has a validation to check if the column index is longer than 255. Is this because of support for some outdated doc formats?

I'm using Apache POI version: 4.0.0

Comment: The `apache poi` `FormlaEvaluator` definitely is wrong when evaluating `OFFSET` for `XSSF` since it uses the old limits of Excel 2003 for column count and row count.

Comment: https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=66614 was just logged - there hopefully be a fix in POI 5.2.4 when that is released.

Answer (score 2):

May be you are using **.xls** file and going to create this type of file. But it not supporting to much columns

**its supports like maximum 65536 rows and 256 columns**

But if you use updated format **XLSX** supports 1048576 rows and 16384 columns

MS Excel supporting corresponding rows and columns

```
+-----------------+-----------+--------------+---------------------+
|                 | Max. Rows | Max. Columns | Max. Cols by letter |
+-----------------+-----------+--------------+---------------------+
| Excel 365*      | 1,048,576 | 16,384       | XFD                 |
| Excel 2013      | 1,048,576 | 16,384       | XFD                 |
| Excel 2010      | 1,048,576 | 16,384       | XFD                 |
| Excel 2007      | 1,048,576 | 16,384       | XFD                 |
| Excel 2003      | 65,536    | 256          | IV                  |
| Excel 2002 (XP) | 65,536    | 256          | IV                  |
| Excel 2000      | 65,536    | 256          | IV                  |
| Excel 97        | 65,536    | 256          | IV                  |
| Excel 95        | 16,384    | 256          | IV                  |
| Excel 5         | 16,384    | 256          | IV                  |
+-----------------+-----------+--------------+---------------------+
```

But here you are using **XSSF** that means your file is in **.xlsx** format so it will support this limit. But if your file are in **.xls** format then this limit is not supported.

If you use **.xlsx** file you can try this code. May be it will help you.

```
private static void writeData() throws IOException {

        Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
        XSSFSheet sheet = (XSSFSheet) workbook.createSheet();

        int r = 0;
        for (int i=0;i<2;i++) {
            Row row = sheet.createRow(r++);
            int column = 0;
            for (int j =0;j<2;j++) {
                XSSFCell cell = (XSSFCell) row.createCell(column++);
                if (r == 1 || column == 1) cell.setCellValue(i);

                else if (column == 2) {
                    cell.setCellFormula("OFFSET(IU220,0,1)");
                }
            }
        }


        FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("stackProblem.xlsx");
        workbook.write(fileOut);
        workbook.close();
    }
```

File looks like this:

[image]

`evaluator.evaluateInCell(cell);` is not supporting for more then 255 columns. you may be use `evaluator.evaluate(cell);`

Try This

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        writeData();
    }

    private static void writeData() throws IOException {

        Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
        XSSFSheet sheet = (XSSFSheet) workbook.createSheet();


        XSSFRow row218 = sheet.createRow(218);
        XSSFCell vv2180 = (XSSFCell) row218.createCell(255);
        vv2180.setCellValue(50);

        XSSFCell vv2181 = (XSSFCell) row218.createCell(256);
        vv2181.setCellValue(69);

        XSSFRow row219 = sheet.createRow(219);
        XSSFCell vv0 = (XSSFCell) row219.createCell(255);
        vv0.setCellValue(40);

        XSSFCell vv = (XSSFCell) row219.createCell(256);
        vv.setCellValue(70);

        XSSFRow row220 = sheet.createRow(220);
        XSSFCell vv2200 = (XSSFCell) row220.createCell(255);
        vv2200.setCellValue(30);

        XSSFCell vv220 = (XSSFCell) row220.createCell(256);
        vv220.setCellValue(20);


        XSSFCell cell = sheet.createRow(1).createCell(1);
        cell.setCellFormula("OFFSET(IV220,0,1)");
        XSSFFormulaEvaluator evaluator =
                (XSSFFormulaEvaluator) workbook.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();

        evaluator.evaluate(cell);


        FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("stackProblem.xlsx");
        workbook.write(fileOut);
        workbook.close();
    }
```

A good reference of poi library : [apche poi HSSF vs XSSF](https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/)

Comment: thanks for your reply! could you please execute this code below in your example and check if the value for variable `cell` is valid (has no `#REF!`) `XSSFCell cell = sheet.getRow(1).createCell(1);
cell.setCellFormula("OFFSET(IV220,0,1)");

XSSFFormulaEvaluator evaluator = 
workbook.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();

evaluator.evaluateInCell(cell)`

Comment: I tried it but it still doesn't work for me. I'm using `xlsx` file format and also `XSSFSheet` implementation in Java. It works when open it in LibreOffice but I need to get the value from `OFFSET` function inside my application. Could you double check if you're able to get no `#REF!` while executing `cell.getRawValue()` for `OFFSET(IV220,0,1)` (use code that I shared in a comment above)

Comment: Yes you are right evaluator.evaluateInCell(cell); function is not working for more than 255 columns you can use evaluator.evaluate(cell); both are almost same validation method but one is working fine and another is not working for more than 255 columns.but may be this method is also serve your problem

Comment: thanks for your efforts! I decided to replace the OFFSET formula by INDEX as that formula seems to be unsupported for for the newest excel formats.